{N}8 Failed to load component from module
NativeScript 8.8.2
I'm new to NativeScript and developing an app following official documentation and tutorials.
I'm trying to navigate to below page

app/components/SelectCentre.vue

while text "Change Centre" is tapped. I've tried different moduleName but none of them actually works and threw the same error: Failed to load component from module.
I've searched on Google and Bing. Viewed some posts and examples. Asked ChatGPT. No working solutions found.
Also I'm a bit curious that is NativeScript deprecated by the community? All {N} related questions on StackOverflow are quite old. The newest I can find were at least 2 year old. Are people using native instead or there is a newer framework that people more prefer to use?
Here are the modules names I tried:

app/components/SelectCentre
@/components/SelectCentre
components/SelectCentre
SelectCentre
app/components/SelectCentre.vue
@/components/SelectCentre.vue
components/SelectCentre.vue
SelectCentre.vue

This is where the navigation text is located.

app/components/Home.vue

<template>
    <Page>
        <FlexboxLayout dock="top" backgroundColor="#00667E" justifyContent="space-between" padding="5 10 10 10" style="font-weight: bold;">
            <FlexboxLayout alignItems="center">
                <Label class="fas" text.decode="&#xf494;" color="white" fontSize="12" />
                <Label color="white" text="CENTRE1" marginLeft="10" />
            </FlexboxLayout>
            <Label color="white" text="Change Centre" style="text-decoration: underline;" @tap="navigateToSelectCentre" />
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    methods: {
        navigateToSelectCentre(event) {
            const page = event.object.page;
            const frame = page.frame;
            console.log(page)
            console.log(frame)
            frame.navigate({
                moduleName: 'components/SelectCentre',
                clearHistory: true,
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>

I want successfully navigate to the targeted page. Great appreciation!
